# I want to sum the total amount of consecutive numbers (similar to a count of consecutive numbers attached)

Tags: excel

In [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-consecutive-monthly-orders) article there is directions on determining the number of consecutive cells greater than 0. I want to do something similar, but instead of simply counting the number of consecutive columns there are, I want to sum them up.

For example, 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 5 would be 3 (1+2=3)

Edit: If for example, there is multiple max consecutive numbers (e.g., 0 0 1 3 0 0 4 5) I would want the highest sum (9) to be chosen.

Edit2: The data is set-up in rows (X axis is months I need to sum for consecutives and Y axis is "user") so the formula would match the examples I've given above.

Comment: What would happen if you have `0 0 1 2 0 0 4 5 0`? Would the sum be `3` or `9` or `12`? Also, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55187217/edit) to let us know what you've tried so far.

Comment: At least show us how your data is set up... in rows? In columns? Tabular format? Such a simple problem but you're not providing us with the most basic information.

Comment: @dwirony the data is set-up in rows

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I would want to sum the max consecutive numbers. In that case the answer would be 9)